# Convert N by N Dataframe to 3 Column Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python 2.7 with Pandas on a Windows 10 machine.

I have an n by n `Dataframe` where:

1) The index represents peoples names

2) The column headers are the same peoples names in the same order

3) Each cell of the `Dataframe`is the average number of times they email each other each day.

How would I transform that `Dataframe`into a `Dataframe`with 3 columns, where:

1) Column 1 would be the index of the n by n `Dataframe`

2) Column 2 would be the row headers of the n by n `Dataframe`

3) Column 3 would be the cell value corresponding to those two names from the index, column header combination from the n by n `Dataframe`

**Edit**

Appologies for not providing an example of what I am looking for. I would like to take df1 and turn it into rel_df, from the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import permutations
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['index'] = ['a', 'b','c','d','e']
df1.set_index('index', inplace = True)
df1['a'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df1['b'] = [1,0,2,3,4]
df1['c'] = [4,1,0,3,4]
df1['d'] = [5,1,2,0,4]
df1['e'] = [7,1,2,3,0]

##df of all relationships to build
flds = pd.Series(SO_df.fld1.unique())
flds = pd.Series(flds.append(pd.Series(SO_df.fld2.unique())).unique())

combos = []
for L in range(0, len(flds)+1):
  for subset in permutations(flds, L):
      if len(subset) == 2:
          combos.append(subset)
      if len(subset) > 2:
          break

rel_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data = combos, columns = ['fld1','fld2'])
rel_df['value'] = [1,4,5,7,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4]

print df1
>>> print df1
       a  b  c  d  e
index               
a      0  1  4  5  7
b      1  0  1  1  1
c      2  2  0  2  2
d      3  3  3  0  3
e      4  4  4  4  0

>>> print rel_df
   fld1 fld2  value
0     a    b      1
1     a    c      4
2     a    d      5
3     a    e      7
4     b    a      1
5     b    c      1
6     b    d      1
7     b    e      1
8     c    a      2
9     c    b      2
10    c    d      2
11    c    e      2
12    d    a      3
13    d    b      3
14    d    c      3
15    d    e      3
16    e    a      4
17    e    b      4
18    e    c      4
19    e    d      4
```

Comment: please provide a sample input data set with 3-5 rows and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [melt](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html):

```
df1 = df1.reset_index()
pd.melt(df1, id_vars='index', value_vars=df1.columns.tolist()[1:])
```

(If in your actual code you're explicitly setting the index as you do here, just skip that step rather than doing the `reset_index`; `melt` doesn't work on an index.)

Comment: I went with this solution because using melt is just one line of code. @Alexander Your solution works as well. I gave you a +1 for that. Thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Flatten your dataframe.
df = df1.stack().reset_index()

# Remove duplicates (e.g. fld1 = 'a' and fld2 = 'a').
df = df.loc[df.iloc[:, 0] != df.iloc[:, 1]]

# Rename columns.
df.columns = ['fld1', 'fld2', 'value']

>>> df
   fld1 fld2  value
1     a    b      1
2     a    c      4
3     a    d      5
4     a    e      7
5     b    a      1
7     b    c      1
8     b    d      1
9     b    e      1
10    c    a      2
11    c    b      2
13    c    d      2
14    c    e      2
15    d    a      3
16    d    b      3
17    d    c      3
19    d    e      3
20    e    a      4
21    e    b      4
22    e    c      4
23    e    d      4
```