# Convert a dataframe with 3 columns to a weighted adjacency matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, graph, adjacency-matrix

I am trying to make a matrix in R, based on a dataframe with 3 columns: 1st column is names of people in a group, 2nd column is also names of people in a group, 3rd column is a value that indicates how well the people match:

```
 Person1 Person2 Match
1     Amber Tiffany     5
2     Amber   James     1
3     Amber Kenneth     7
4     Amber  Gordon     9
5   Tiffany   James     4
6   Tiffany Kenneth     6
7   Tiffany  Gordon     6
8     James Kenneth     3
9     James  Gordon     7
10 Kenneth   Gordon     2

etc
```

(in fact it's many more names and values)

I want the names of the people on both axes of the matrix, like this:

|  | Amber | Tiffany | James | Kenneth | Gordon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amber | 0 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 9 |
| Tiffany | 5 | 0 | 4 | 6 | 6 |
| James | 1 | 4 | 0 | 3 | 7 |
| Kenneth | 7 | 6 | 3 | 0 | 2 |
| Gordon | 9 | 6 | 7 | 2 | 0 |

I can't find an easy way to do this.
I've read and tried several things, such as:

- [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format)
- [R: Create 3 column dataframe from sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36917644/r-create-3-column-dataframe-from-sparse-matrix)
- [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)
- [Reshape three column data frame to matrix ("long" to "wide" format)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9617348/reshape-three-column-data-frame-to-matrix-long-to-wide-format)

But I didn't succeed yet.

Comment: use `xtabs(Match ~ Person1 + Person2, df1)`

Answer (score 1):

An option with `igraph`

```
get.adjacency(
  graph_from_data_frame(df, directed = FALSE),
  attr = "Match",
  sparse = FALSE
)
```

gives

```
        Amber Tiffany James Kenneth Gordon
Amber       0       5     1       7      9
Tiffany     5       0     4       6      6
James       1       4     0       3      7
Kenneth     7       6     3       0      2
Gordon      9       6     7       2      0
```

**Data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(Person1 = c("Amber", "Amber", "Amber", "Amber", 
"Tiffany", "Tiffany", "Tiffany", "James", "James", "Kenneth"),
    Person2 = c("Tiffany", "James", "Kenneth", "Gordon", "James",
    "Kenneth", "Gordon", "Kenneth", "Gordon", "Gordon"), Match = c(5L,
    1L, 7L, 9L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1",
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would first create an empty matrix:

```
allpersons <- union(df$Person1, df$Person2)
mat <- matrix(0, nrow=length(allpersons), ncol=length(allpersons),
              dimnames=list(allpersons, allpersons))
```

And then add all the values from the third column of `df` by row and column name pairs:

```
mat[as.matrix(df[,c(1,2)])] <- df[,3]
mat[as.matrix(df[,c(2,1)])] <- df[,3]
```

Note - because the matrix has to be symmetrical the values are added two times: once for row-column pairs and then again for column-row pairs.

Result:

```
        Amber Tiffany James Kenneth Gordon
Amber       0       5     1       7      9
Tiffany     5       0     4       6      6
James       1       4     0       3      7
Kenneth     7       6     3       0      2
Gordon      9       6     7       2      0
```